# How to add a route in hapi 0.8.4

Tags: javascript, node.js, hapi.js

I have a little problem with this simple code to start a server with nodejs and Hapi. 
This is the code:

```
var Hapi = require('hapi');

var http = new Hapi.Server('0.0.0.0', 8080);

http.route({
  method: 'GET',
  path: '/api',
  handler: function(request, reply) {
    reply({ 'api' : 'hello!' });
  }
}
);

http.start();
```

and this is the error :

```
http.route({
     ^
TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Prova.js:8:6)
    at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:501:10)
    at startup (node.js:129:16)
    at node.js:814:3
```

It' a very basilar code but i can't understand why it has a problem with http.route.

Comment: Which version of Hapi do you have installed?

Comment: 0.8.4? Are you sure? Latest is 8.8.0.

Comment: @robertklep node_moduls/Hapi/package.json 
"name": "hapi",
  "description": "HTTP API Server framework",
  "homepage": "http://hapijs.com",
  "version": "0.8.4",
  "author": {
    "name": "Eran Hammer",
    "email": "eran@hueniverse.com",
    "url": "http://hueniverse.com"

Comment: I don't know if you're stuck with that version, but if not I would suggest upgrading to a recent version. I think that your code is failing because you're mixing old and new syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In hapi 0.8.4 you can add routes with `addRoute()`:

```
var Hapi = require('hapi');

// Create a server with a host and port
var server = new Hapi.Server('localhost', 8000);

// Define the route
var hello = {
    handler: function (request) {

        request.reply({ greeting: 'hello world' });
    }
};

// Add the route
server.addRoute({
    method: 'GET',
    path: '/hello',
    config: hello
});

// Start the server
server.start();
```

But that version of hapi is very old, you should upgrade it to the latest. The current stable version of hapi is 8.8.0.